# How will you block access of Drupal admin login page from untrusted IPs without using nginx.conf?

Tags: security, drupal-7

Recently I was going through this task and did a lot of Rnd. Everyone suggested me to use location block in nginx like:

```
location = /user {
    include /path/to/trusted-ips.txt;
    deny all;
}
```

But due to some nginx rewrite rules it is not working. I have implemented another solution using drupal form hook and sharing with you.

Answer (score 0):

```
function hook_form_alter (&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
        if($form_id == 'user_login') {
        $forbidden = "<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head><body><center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center><hr><center>nginx</center></body>";
        $allowed_ip_file = '/path/to/trusted-ips.txt';
        $allowed_ip_file = fopen($allowed_ip_file, "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
        $allowd_ip_arr = array();
        while(! feof($allowed_ip_file)) {
            $line = fgets($allowed_ip_file);
            if (preg_match('/\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}/', $line, $ip_match)) {
                $allowd_ip_arr[] = $ip_match[0];
            }
        }
        fclose($allowed_ip_file);
        if(!in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $allowd_ip_arr)) {
            http_response_code(403);
            echo $forbidden; exit();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [Restrict IP Drupal module](https://www.drupal.org/project/restrict_ip)
This module allows administrators to restrict access to the site to an administrator defined set of IP addresses.